# Resize GIF animation

Tags: android, resize, gif

I'm saving a .gif on the phone, and then display it on the device. It works fine on a WVGA, but on HVGA it cuts of most of the animation because of screen size. **How can I resize it to fit screen?**

```
    private Movie movie;

    //onDraw...     
    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    if (moviestart == 0)
    { // first time
        moviestart = now;
    }

    if (movie != null)
    {
        int relTime = (int) ((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
        movie.setTime(relTime);
        movie.draw(canvas, -10, -80); 
    }
```

I'm not displaying the whole animation either, I'm cutting about 20% off on top.

Comment: I do not think that you can resize a .gif file. As far as I know, any resize will ruin the animation. Please check Movie where this might be possible without resizing the gif directly.

Comment: Well the idea is not to change gif, but to change just the display, so Movie. But I didn't find anything on that so far